# A one-to-one map between $M_{n\times n}$ and the $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, metric-spaces

I've been trying to think in something that can make this happen, but i'm not get anywhere. Plus, i have to show something through this map that can make this space($M_{n\times n}$) a metric space, so a think to use the trace of a matrix. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace of matrix is invalid since it reduces the dimension from $n^2$ to $n$. You can define the set of $n\times n$ matrices  with [Frobenius norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) and reorder the rows of the matrices back to back and define the Euclidean $2$-norm on $\Bbb R^{n^2}$. In this manner the two metric spaces would become [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism).

Comment: Actually, $\mathrm{tr}:M_{n\times n}\to\mathbb R$ reduces the dimension to just $1$.

Comment: I mean the degree of freedom reduces to $n$ since only diagonal entries are important.

Comment: Yeah, i saw my mistake about the trace. I'm gonna look the sugestion of Frobenius norm here, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I also can help you further if you needed....

Comment: @Federico actually, any metric $m: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ has dimension 1 codomain, so I don't think that affects anything...

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner Yes, I understand that; just the sentence _"The trace of matrix reduces the dimension from $n^2$ to $n$"_ is not completely transparent to me

Comment: @Federico Ah, well as Mostafa explains in the comment, the point is that the trace map is not injective and so trying to define something like $|tr(A-B)|$ produces, at best, a pseudometric.

Comment: In fact, the two spaces become isometric under this choice of metrics, which is important for what the OP trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

Just take 
$$
f:A\to (a_{1,1},a_{1,2},\dots,a_{1,n},a_{2,1},\dots a_{2,n},a_{3,1}\dots,a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\dots, a_{n,n})
$$
i.e just rearrange the entries of $A$ into a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
Then define $d(A,B):=||f(A)-f(B)||$.

Comment: But this map is one-to-one? I think that $$f:A\rightarrow (a_{1,1},..., a_{1,n}, a_{2,1}...,a{2,n},...,a_{n,1},...,a_{n,n})$$ answer the question, but i'm not sure of that.

Comment: Take n=3. If $A=\begin{array}{lcr} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & j \end{array}$ and $B = \begin{array}{lcr} a & b & c \\ k & l & m \\ g & h & j \end{array}$.  So $A\neq B$ but f(A)=f(B)

Comment: No problem, anyway you helped me a lot, thank you so much.

Comment: @gbcosta no problem

Comment: Your objection : "Take n=3..." is not valid : we order the entries f(A)=(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) is different from f(B)=(a, b, c, k, l, m, g, h, i) !

Comment: Yes, i know. I showed this because him wrote wrong but already edited.